# How to find SQL Server running port when you don't own the server?

Tags: sql-server

In our enterprise I don't have access to MSSQL Server, so I can'r access the system tables.

Comment: Ask the dbas. You should not be trying to find this information unless you have a valid relationship to the owner of the database in which case, there is no reason not to ask them directly.

Answer (score 2):

What works for me is:

1. capture the network traffic `Wireshark` (run as Administrator, select Network Interface),while opening connection to server.
2. Find the ip address with `ping`
3. filter with `ip.dst == x.x.x.x`

The port is shown in the column `info` in the format `src.port -> dst.port`

Answer (score 0):

If you have elevated rights to SQL but not the OS, you can query the log.

If you don't have access to the OS but can run queries, perhaps try:

```
USE master
GO
xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on' 
GO
```

If you don't have elevated rights to SQL, from the client-side windows machine with an active connection, you could run a netstat command and see on which ports you are connected to the target. Filter on IP address of the host.

```
netstat -an | find "10.1.10.xxx"
```

[image: netstat demo]

You'll see that I have connections to the host on 3389 and 1433. Maybe this helps narrow it down.

Comment: No I don't have rights to the system tables. To access the Database from Powershell via `system.data.sqlclient` i need the port. When you request the connectionstring you mostly get it without port information. Why this is so, I don;t know. I can ask the SQL-Team and they look it up on the server. With wireshark I can find out from the Client side